# Is my priority queue test program very slow because I am not using Go correctly?

Tags: go

I wrote this crude min heap code that is a translation of a similar program I wrote in C++.  I think I must be using slices incorrectly because the go code is way slower than the C++ code.  Inserting and deleting 100,000 integers takes about 19 seconds in Go, but only 1.73 seconds in C++.  Can anyone offer some advice?  Or is Go that much slower than C++?  I time the code like this under Linux: "time ./pqgo -n 100000 -d 100000 >/dev/null". Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
       "fmt"
       "time"
       "math/rand"
       "flag"
)

func insert( key int, lPq []int) []int {
    lPq = append( lPq[:], key )
    i := len(lPq) - 1

    for ; i > 1 && lPq[ i/2 ] > lPq[i] ; {
        lTemp := lPq[ i/2 ]
        lPq[ i/2 ] =  lPq[i]
        lPq[i] = lTemp
        i = i / 2
    }
    return lPq
}

func delete_min( lPq []int) (int, []int) {
  lRetVal := lPq[1]

    lPq[1] = lPq[ len(lPq)-1 ]
    lPq = lPq[0:len(lPq)-1 ]

  k := 1
  for ; 2*k <= len(lPq); {
  j := 2*k
  if k < len(lPq) && lPq[j] > lPq[j+1] {
      j++
    }
  if lPq[k] <= lPq[j] {
    break
    }
    lTemp := lPq[k]
    lPq[k] = lPq[j]
  lPq[j] = lTemp
    }
    return lRetVal, lPq
}

func main() {
  var lPq []int
    lPq = append(lPq[:], -9999)

    var ip *int = flag.Int("n", 8, "help message")
    var ip2 *int = flag.Int("d", 8, "help message2")
        flag.Parse()
        lNum := *ip

        fmt.Printf( "lNum= %d\n", lNum)   

    lPq = insert( 17, lPq[:] );
    lPq = insert( 19, lPq[:] );
    lPq = insert( 9, lPq[:] );
    lPq = insert( 4 , lPq[:]);
    lPq = insert ( 12, lPq[:] );

        rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
        for i := 0; i < lNum; i++ {
        lKey := rand.Intn( 4*lNum )
            lPq = insert(lKey, lPq[:])    
    }
    fmt.Printf("pq.size = %d\n", len(lPq) )

        lPrintTo := len(lPq)
    if lPrintTo > 64 {
          lPrintTo = 64
      }
        var num int
        for _, num = range lPq[0:lPrintTo] {
        fmt.Printf( "%d ", num)
    }
    fmt.Println("");

    var lMin int
    for index := 1; index < 3; index++ {
        lMin, lPq = delete_min( lPq[:] )
            fmt.Printf( "lMin = %d\n", lMin)
            for _, num = range lPq[0:lPrintTo] {
        fmt.Printf( "%d ", num)
      }
      fmt.Println("");
    }

  lPq = insert( 3, lPq[:] );
  lPq = insert( 4, lPq[:] );
  lPq = insert( 1, lPq[:] );
  lPq = insert( 8, lPq[:] );
  lPq = insert( 20, lPq[:] );
  lPq = insert( 21, lPq[:] );
  lPq = insert( 6, lPq[:] );
  lPq = insert ( 11, lPq[:]  );

    lNumToDelete := len( lPq )
    lNumToDelete = *ip2

    for index := 1; index < lNumToDelete-1; index++ {
    lMin, lPq = delete_min( lPq[:] )

        lPrintTo = len(lPq)
        if lPrintTo > 64 {
          lPrintTo = 64
      }
        fmt.Printf("lPrintTo = %d\n",lPrintTo )
      fmt.Printf("pq.size = %d\n", len(lPq) )
      for _, num = range lPq[0:lPrintTo] {
            fmt.Printf( "%d ", num)
      }
    fmt.Println("");
    }

}

// gccgo -Og -I/devserv-home/rspikol/include -o pqgo pq.go -L/devserv-home/rspikol/lib
```

Comment: A side comment. It would be nice if you could indent your code according to Go standard. You don't have to do that manually, the tool "gofmt" will do it for you, or alternatively, you can use the "Format" button of the Playground. That would make your code much easier to read for people used to write and read Go code. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your C++ version generate the same amount of output?

The last loop runs `lNumToDelete` (100,000) times, and prints up to 64 values from the queue on each iteration.  That is a lot of output, and it takes time to format and write out, even if it is going to `/dev/null`.

Commenting out the `fmt.Printf()` calls inside the delete loop made the program run significantly faster for me.

A few other suggestions:

- `fmt.Printf("a = %d\n", b)` can be replaced with `fmt.Println("a =", b)`
- `lPq[:]` can be replaced with `lPq`
- Check out the Go profiling tools: http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs

Comment: Also wonder if `rand` speed is part of it, since I doubt Go's RNG is hyper-optimized. If profiling shows it is, you could replace it with a silly stub that generates not-very-pseudorandom-but-still-evenly distributed numbers (`r=(r^const1)*(const2|1); r^=r>>const3;` or whatever) if you wanted to work around that.

Comment: Thanks!  I missed the fmt.Printf() inside the delete loop.  Yes, I/O is definitely a time sink even if it is redirected!